# C# and Excel: Writing on multiple sheets, it always writes on the first?

Tags: c#, excel

It seems like I have a logical mistake. But how? It seems to be all right for me. What am I doing wrong? The sheets are created. But the whole content is on the first sheet.
I even remember once I hardcoded .get_Item(2) and it wrote on the second sheet, why isn't it now?

```
public void createXls()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        for (int z = 1; z <= Sheets.Count; z++)
        {
            if (z > 1) xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(misValue, misValue, 1, misValue);
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(z);
            Console.WriteLine("We are writing on sheet #" + z); // it says ...1, 2, 3, 4, 5
            for (int y = 1; y <= Sheets[z - 1].Count; y++)
            {
                int x = 1;
                foreach (var Column in Sheets[z - 1][y - 1])
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[y, x] = Column.Value;
                    x++;
                }
            }
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        }


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("\\\\psf\\Home\\Desktop\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I may be blind, where is `Sheets` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that something is wrong with your sample - `Sheets` is not a variable nor a class is scope.

When I changed occurrences of `Sheets` to `xlWorkBook.Sheets`, I got an unhandled COM exception saying that index is invalid.

I think that the most likely explanation of your problem is that you assigned `Sheets` somewhere in code you didn't paste in the sample. You should also double-check that your indices are correct and that you use indexers on the right objects.

**Irrelevant hints:**

You can use indexed property instead of `get_Item` e.g. `[2]` instead of `get_Item(2)`.

Local variables should start with lowercase (e.g. `column` should be use instead of `Column`).

Comment: Oh, that might be confusing, but Sheets is a public declared variable of me. But thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this.

```
public class Tyburn1
{
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    public Tyburn1()
    {
        Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        oSheet.Name = "The first sheet";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Something";
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet2 = oWB.Sheets.Add(missing, missing, 1, missing) 
                        as Excel.Worksheet;
        oSheet2.Name = "The second sheet";
        oSheet2.Cells[1, 1] = "Something completely different";
        string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)        
                                + "\\SoSample.xlsx";
        oWB.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
            missing, missing, missing, missing,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
        oXL.UserControl = true;
        oXL.Quit();
    }
}
```

The statement that adds the second sheet is...

```
Excel.Worksheet oSheet2 = oWB.Sheets.Add(missing, missing, 1, missing) 
                            as Excel.Worksheet;
```

the '1' argument specifies a single sheet, and it can be more if you want to add several sheets at once.

Final note: the statement oXL.Visible = false; tells Excel to start in silent mode.